# jQuery replaceWith() documentation

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I am working through the jQuery documentation and found a piece of a replaceWith() example (the last example from http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) that I don't fully understand.  I will post a link to this post as a comment on the jQuery documentation replaceWith() page to aid others new to jQuery and DOM manipulation.

Specifically, I do not fully understand the behavior of "$container" in:

```
"$("p").append( $container.attr("class") );"
```

I was expecting the above code to append the word "inner" to the "p" contents because the "replaceWith()" method was called when the variable was created:

```
var $container = $("div.container").replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).contents();
});
```

However, "$("p").append( $container.attr("class") );" actually appends the word "container", not the word "inner".

It seems that the variable "$container" actually references the div that was replaced, "$("div.container")", not the replacing content, "$(this).contents();".

Two questions:

1. **What is "replaceWith()" doing in this context?**
2. **Is there something special going on with the order of operations or the "attr()" method that I am not seeing?**

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
    .container { background-color: #991; }
    .inner { color: #911; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
    <button>Replace!</button>
</p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Scooby</div>
    <div class="inner">Dooby</div>
    <div class="inner">Doo</div>
</div>

<script>
$('button').bind("click", function() {
    **var $container = $("div.container").replaceWith(function() {
        return $(this).contents();
    });**

    **$("p").append( $container.attr("class") );**
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the `.replaceWith()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

> The `.replaceWith()` method, like most jQuery methods, returns the jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. **However, it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned**. This object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not the new element that has replaced it.

...so what you're seeing is the expected behavior, `$container` should and does refer to what *was* replaced, not the replacement.

Comment: Thank you Nick!  As a newbie to jQuery, I was simply confused about the definition of 'jQuery object' and glossed over "the object refers to the element" section of the text.  Much appreciated.